# JavaFX TabPane not filling space

Tags: layout, javafx, javafx-8, tabpanel

I've placed some content inside a TabPane's tab, but the TabPane's width seems to me being equal to the longest element inside the tab (the longest element is not visible on the picture).

The TabPane is inside an AnchorPane with zero valued anchors, that's why I would expect it to fill the whole space, not just the size of the longest element inside..

[image: tabPane]

How could I make the TabPane fill all available space?

UPDATE:

I've forgot to mention, that my a TabView is loaded through the FXMLLoader.load() method and it's added as a child to the AnchorPane..

Comment: Check your anchor pane constraints on your tab pane.  It will be easier to help you if you post your code, or an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the tabPane in the code, you could try like this :

```
    AnchorPane anchorPaneContent = new AnchorPane();
    TabPane node = new TabPane();
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(node, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(node, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(node, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(node, 0.0);
    anchorPaneContent.getChildren().add(node);
```

If you add the tabPane in the SceneBuilder, you just need to make the tabpane fit it's parent by right clicking on the node.